# Bypassing Office365 Server Send As Denial

Tags: email-spoofing, smtp, powershell

I am trying to send an e-mail via Windows Powershell ISE using Office365's hosting server, on behalf of another user which is specified in `FROM` part of the code using. But when I try to do this, I get: `"STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:SendAsDeniedException.MapiExceptionSendAsDenied; Failed to process message due to a permanent exception with message [BeginDiagnosticData]Cannot submit message."` error. Since it seems like Office365 doesn't allow users to send e-mails on behalf of other users unlike gmail smtp system.

The code I use is simply as below:

```
$Username = "MyUserName";
$Password = "MyPassword";

    function Send-ToEmail([string]$email){
    
        $message = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage;
        $message.From = "YourName@outlook.com";
        $message.To.Add($email);
        $message.Subject = "subject text here...";
        $message.Body = "body text here...";
    
        $smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com", "587");
        $smtp.EnableSSL = $true;
        $smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $Password);
        $smtp.send($message);
        write-host "Mail Sent" ; 
     }
    Send-ToEmail  -email "reciever@outlook.com"
```

So what I would like to know is if there is a way to bypass such restriction and send e-mails with different sender name.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"is a way to bypass such restriction and send e-mails with different sender name."* - asking on how to bypass existing security policies is off-topic here.